# Drag and Drop input for files not handling files

Tags: javascript, html, file, drag-and-drop

I've made a form where the user can upload a file and I wanted to add a drag and drop feature so I made it like this:

```
<small id="filename"></small>
<!-- <input id="thumbnail" type="file" name="thumbnail"  class="input input-thumbnail form-control"> -->
<div class="dropzone" id="droparea">
    <div class="input-container">
        <input type="file" class="dropzone-input" id="thumbnail-input" name="thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="overlay">
        <small class="overlay-text" id="overlay-text">Drag and Drop</small>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    (function() {
    let dropzone = document.getElementById('droparea');
    let dropzonetext = document.getElementById('overlay-text');
    let filenametext = document.getElementById('filename');
    let fileImput = document.getElementById('thumbnail-input');

    dropzone.ondrop = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.className = 'dropzone';
        dropzonetext.className = 'overlay';
        fileImput.files[0] = e.target.files[0];
        filenametext = fileImput.files[0].name
    };

    dropzone.ondragover = function() {
        this.className = 'dropzone dragover';
        dropzonetext.className = 'overlay dragover';
        return false;
    };

    dropzone.ondragleave = function() {
        this.className = 'dropzone';
        dropzonetext.className = 'overlay';
        return false;
    };
}());
</script>
```

The expected behavior of this code is that the box changes color (controlled by css) whenever the user hovers over it when holding 1 or multiple files (I want to limit it to only accept 1 file). But this does not work.

Also whenever the file is dropped on the box the value of the input should become the file dropped by the user but this is not happening either.

Instead I'm getting this error in the console whenever I drop the file there:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.dropzone.ondrop ((index):79)
dropzone.ondrop @ (index):79
```

With line 79 being: `fileImput.files[0] = e.target.files[0];`

What is causing this problem?

Here is also the css for the drag and drop:

```
.dropzone-input{
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0)
    width: 30vw;
    height: 25vh;
    z-index:0;
    position: absolute;
    color: #ccc;
    line-height:25vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.dragover{
    border-color: black;
    text-color: black;
}
.dropzone {
    width: 30vw;
    height: 25vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px dashed #ccc;
}

.overlay {
    width: 30vw;
    height: 25vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:1;
    line-height:25vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.overlay-text{
    color: darkgrey;
}

.overlay-text.dragover{
    text-color: black;
}
```

**EDIT: **

Someone asked for a screenshot:
[image]

you can see the file selected is the one I dropped on the input

Comment: it because e.target.file is null

Comment: how can I make it not null?

Answer (score 0):

The result is that, e.target.files is null. Because you set event ondrop on dropzone, so e.target maybe any ele in dropzone where you drop (detail in the picture test on my local)[image]. But some elements don't have files property. The ele which have files property is the input. So you should try 1 option:

Option 1,set the ondrop event for only the input

Option 2, check the e.target .
if(e.target is input) use

```
fileImput.files[0] = e.target.files[0];
```

else use

```
fileImput.files[0] = e.target.parentElement.querySelector('#thumbnail-input').files[0];
```

Comment: i have test on my local and it work ok? can you give me a screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162760/discussion-between-ngo-tuan-and-brhsm).